# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

I get following Error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in......

Here is my Query:

```
$query = "SELECT ListNumber FROM residential"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >10){ 
    $difference = mysql_num_rows($result1) - 10; 
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM `residential` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 10,". $difference; 
    $result2 = mysql_query($myQuery); 
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_BOTH))
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your query ($myQuery) is failing and therefore not producing a query resource, but instead producing FALSE.

To reveal what your dynamically generated query looks like and reveal the errors, try this:

```
$result2 = mysql_query($myQuery) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

The error message will guide you to the solution, which from your comment below is related to using ORDER BY on a field that doesn't exist in the table you're SELECTing from.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted doesn't include a call to `mysql_fetch_array()`. However, what is most likely going wrong is that you are issuing a query that returns an error message, in which case the return value from the query function is `false`, and attempting to call `mysql_fetch_array()` on it doesn't work (because boolean `false` is not a mysql result object).

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given in php error on server if you get this error :  `please select all privileges on your server`. u will get the answer..

Answer (score -1):

This error comes when there is error in your query syntax check field names table name, mean check your query syntax.